# coreml Failed to get the home directory when checking model path

Tags: swiftui, coreml, createml

I wanted to create an image classifier with create ML.
However, when I build, I get this error.

The target and path are correct, but I don't know why I'm getting this error.

Tried to set the path correctly.
But even if I set it to the correct path, I get this error.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Probably because your app is still sandboxed

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was making sure that I was testing the model on an actual device, not the simulator.(Make sure the path to the model is also correct)

Answer (score 0):

Check file extension, it must be in your filepath string. Something like this: `/var/.../classifier.mlmodelc` not `/var/.../classifier`.

Also check that you're using this init method:
`init(fileURLWithPath path: String)` for `URL` class not this
`init?(string: String)`.